# RestKit 0.20.0pre5: HTTP headers per request

Tags: http-headers, restkit

i want to send an `If-Modified-Since` http header with a GET request, issued by `[RKObjectManager getObjectsAtPath:...]`.

the [migration guide](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0) tells that i can set only "global" default request headers for an  `RKObjectManager` instance:

```
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:url];
[objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"If-Modified-Since" value:@"Sat, 29 Dec 2012 19:43:31 GMT"];
```

since i want to keep a centralized `RKObjetManager` instance (via `[RKObjectManager sharedManaged]`), this is not really a good option.

is creating a specific `RKObjectManager` before each request and set my http headers as "default" the only solution or is there a better way?

Comment: Why can't you make your objectManager the shared instance like this: [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few options here:

1. Obtain an `NSURLRequest` object using `requestWithObject:method:path:parameters:`, configure the `NSURLRequest` appropriately, and then invoke `objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` or `managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:managedObjectContext:success:failure:`. This will let you configure the requests on a one-off basis.
2. Configure a custom subclass of `RKHTTPRequestOperation` via `setHTTPOperationClass:` on `RKObjectManager`. This will let you hook subclass in that can configure every NSURLRequest as the object manager makes requests, letting you centralize the configuration.
3. On the latest development branch, you can also register a subclass of `RKObjectRequestOperation` with the manager that will be used for requests of your choosing, enabling you to centralize customization at the object request operation level.

Options 1 or 2 are probably most appropriate for the HTTP level concern you outline, but I mention as an alternative for doing the same sort of customization at the object mapping level.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions blake! gonna give it a try the day after tomorrow when i'm back on the project. let you know how it worked out :-)

Comment: so according to the comments here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/928 - does RestKit  even need to bother with a custom If-Modified-Since?